# scala - map.get returns None for null key but not for null value

Tags: scala

Is there any better way to do following?

```
val v = map.get(key)
      v match {
        case None => default
        case Some(str) => {
          if(str == null) default else str << how to avoid additional null check here
        }
      }
```

Comment: Flippant-but-somewhat-serious answer: don't put nulls in your map.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Option.apply` works intelligently with `null`:

```
val myNullString: String = null
Option(myNullString) //None
```

So one option would be:

```
map.get(key).flatMap(Option.apply).getOrElse(default)
```

You could also filter all the `null` values from the map first.  You might also be interested in the `getOrElse` or `withDefaultValue` methods on `Map` for these types of operations:

```
map.filter(_._2 != null).getOrElse(key, default)
map.filterNot(_._2 == null).withDefaultValue(default)(key)
```

You could also use `collectFirst` here (this is more general, since you can apply it to arbitrary key-value tuples, but you lose the efficiency of constant lookup):

```
map collectFirst { case (`key`, str) if str != null => str } getOrElse default
```